# Add a new calculated column from 2 values in RDD

Tags: scala, datetime, apache-spark, rdd

I have 2 paired RDDs that I joined them together using the same key and I now I want to add a new calculated column using 2 columns from the values part. The new joined RDD type is:

```
RDD[((String, Int), Iterable[((String, DateTime, Int,Int), (String, DateTime, String, String))])]
```

I want to add another field to the new RDD which show the delta between the 2 `DateTime` fields.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just map over your RDD and produce a row with the new field? If that's not working for you, please provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using `map` to extend the 2-tuples into 3-tuples, roughly as follows:

```
joined.map{ case (key, values) =>
  val delta = computeDelta(values)
  (key, values, delta)
}
```

Or, more concisely:

```
joined.map{ case (k, vs) => (k, vs, computeDelta(vs)) }
```

Then your `computeDelta` function can just extract the first and second values of type `(String, DateTime, Int,Int)`, get the second item (`DateTime`) from each and compute the delta using whatever `DateTime` functions are convenient.

If you want your output RDD to still be a paired RDD, then you will need to wrap the new delta field into a tuple, roughly as follows:

```
joined.mapValues{ values =>
  val delta = computeDelta(values)
  (values, delta)
}
```

which will preserve the original PairedRDD keys, and give you values of type `(Iterable[(String, DateTime, Int,Int)], Long)`

(assuming you are calculating deltas of type `Long`)