# Add column to RDD Spark 1.2.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to expend my RDD table by one column (with string values) using [this question answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29963117/2552806) but I cannot add a column name this way... I'm using Scala.

Is there any easy way to add a column to RDD?

Comment: Check if the information on this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622867/add-a-new-calculated-column-from-2-values-in-rdd

Comment: Can you show us some piece of code you're trying to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Spark has a *functional approach* to the elaboration of data. Fundamentally, an `RDD[T]` is some sort of collection of objects (`RDD` stands for *Resilient Distributed Data structure*).

Following the functional approach, you elaborate the objects inside the `RDD` using *transformations*. Transformations construct a new `RDD` from a previous one.

One example of transformation is the `map` method. Using `map`, you can transform each object of your `RDD` in every other type of object you need. So, if you have a data structure that represents a *row*, you can trasform that structure in a new one with an added row.

For example, take the following piece of code.

```
val rdd: (String, String) = sc.pallelize(List(("Hello", "World"), ("Such", "Wow"))
// This new RDD will have one more "column",  
// which is the concatenation of the previous
val rddWithOneMoreColumn = 
  rdd.map {
    case(a, b) => 
      (a, b, a + b)
```

In this example an `RDD` of `Tuple2` (a.k.a. a couple) is transformed into an `RDD` of `Tuple3`, simply applying a function to each `RDD` element.

Clearly, you have to apply an action over the object `rddWithOneMoreColumn` to make the computation happen. In fact, Apache Spark computes lazily the result of all of your transformation.

Comment: But what if my data in the original RDD is rows from Cassandra table?

Comment: Which type are the objects you are extracting from Cassandra?

Comment: "But what if my data in the original RDD is rows from Cassandra table?" Then you have to tell us that, as most of us are not telepathic.

Comment: @Rada: then you still have to use some sort of transformation on the row objects, or you can use the withColumn method on DataFrames.